# Unable to access column alias in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, column-alias

I am trying to filter rows from my Postgres database with below query. Everything works fine but when I try to check if `latesttask` column is null or has some value then it shows error:

> error: column "latesttask" does not exist

```
SELECT *, 
  (
    SELECT 
      JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'id', taskhistories.id, 'task', taskhistories.task, 
        'taskname', t.name, 'project', taskhistories.project, 
        'projectname', p.name, 'started_at', 
        taskhistories.started_at, 'stopped_at', 
        taskhistories.stopped_at
      ) 
    FROM 
      tasks AS t, 
      projects AS p, 
      latesttasks, 
      taskhistories 
    WHERE 
      taskhistories.user = users.id 
      AND latesttasks.task = t.id 
      AND latesttasks.project = p.id 
      AND taskhistories.id = latesttasks.taskhistory 
      AND (
        LOWER(t.name) LIKE '%we%' 
        OR LOWER(p.name) LIKE '%we%'
      )
  ) as latestttask 
FROM 
  users 
WHERE 
  (
    latesttask IS NULL 
    AND (
      LOWER(name) LIKE '%we%' 
      OR LOWER(email) LIKE '%we%'
    ) 
    OR latesttask IS NOT NULL
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

One "t" to many in your column alias `latestttask`.

But, more importantly, you cannot reference output column names in the `WHERE` clause anyway. There would have to be a column `users.latesttask` to make the `WHERE` clause work.

This would be a working equivalent with a `LEFT JOIN` to a `LATERAL` subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_build_object(
              'id', h.id, 'task', h.task, 
              'taskname', t.name, 'project', h.project, 
              'projectname', p.name, 'started_at', h.started_at,
              'stopped_at', h.stopped_at) AS latesttask 
   FROM   tasks         t
   JOIN   latesttasks   l ON l.task = t.id 
   JOIN   projects      p ON p.id = l.project
   JOIN   taskhistories h ON h.id = l.taskhistory 
   WHERE  h.user = u.id 
   AND   (lower(t.name) LIKE '%we%' 
       OR lower(p.name) LIKE '%we%')
   ) l ON true
WHERE  l.latesttask IS NOT NULL
   OR  lower(u.name) LIKE '%we%'
   OR  lower(u.email) LIKE '%we%';
```

Comment: Hi @Erwin, Thank you for your time. I have tried with `users.latesttask` but then it  returns same error for `users.latesttask`

Comment: Because there is no such column, I assume.

Comment: yes, this is what I am confused about accessing **latesttask** column which is alias column in WHERE clause

Comment: It is not like I am not getting any value in latesttask column. I am getting proper json object in that field but when I add it in WHERE clause condition then it gives me error.

Comment: Try reading the second sentence of my answer.

Comment: ohh, okay. got it.

Is there any other workaround to achieve this?

Comment: @DrashtiKheni: Sure, various ways. I added an alternative query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250784/discussion-between-drashti-kheni-and-erwin-brandstetter).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  I am interested in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74980692/optimize-query-contains-join-and-subquery?noredirect=1#comment132320943_74980692), can you spare some time, look at it.

Comment: @jian: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74980692/optimize-query-contains-join-and-subquery) is a lazy question with most useful context missing, and the OP seems unresponsive. So no, not touching it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with...

```
Select * from (SELECT 
  *, 
  (
    SELECT 
      JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'id', taskhistories.id, 'task', taskhistories.task, 
        'taskname', t.name, 'project', taskhistories.project, 
        'projectname', p.name, 'started_at', 
        taskhistories.started_at, 'stopped_at', 
        taskhistories.stopped_at
      ) 
    FROM 
      tasks AS t, 
      projects AS p, 
      latesttasks, 
      taskhistories 
    WHERE 
      taskhistories.user = users.id 
      AND latesttasks.task = t.id 
      AND latesttasks.project = p.id 
      AND taskhistories.id = latesttasks.taskhistory 
      AND (
        LOWER(t.name) LIKE '%we%' 
        OR LOWER(p.name) LIKE '%we%'
      )
  ) as latesttask 
FROM 
  users ) a 
WHERE 
  (
    latesttask IS NULL 
    AND (
      LOWER(name) LIKE '%we%' 
      OR LOWER(email) LIKE '%we%'
    ) 
    OR latesttask IS NOT NULL
  )
```

Comment: Though this is not exact answer I was looking for but helped me to reach to required answer. Thank you so much for your time.