# Optimize Query contains join and SubQuery

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I need to run this query but it takes so long and I got timeout exception.
would you please help me how can I decrease the execution time of this query or how how can I make it simpler?
here is my Postgres Query:

```
 select
    AR1.patient_id,
    CONCAT(Ac."firstName", ' ', Ac."lastName") as doctor_full_name,
    to_json(Ac.expertise::json->0->'id')::text as expertise_id,
    to_json(Ac.expertise::json->0->'title')::text as expertise_title,
    AP."phoneNumbers" as mobile,
    AC.account_id as account_id,
    AC.city_id
from
    tb1 as AR1
LEFT JOIN tb2 as AA
    on AR1.appointment_id = AA.id
LEFT JOIN tb3 as AC
        on AC.account_id = AA.appointment_owner_id
LEFT JOIN tb4 as AP
        on AP.id = AR1.patient_id


where AR1.status = 'canceled'
and AR1.updated_at >= '2022-12-30 00:00:00'
and AR1.updated_at < '2022-12-30 23:59:59'
and  AP."phoneNumbers" <> ''
and patient_id not in (
    select
            AR2.patient_id
    from
     tb1 as AR2
 LEFT JOIN tb2 as AA2
    on AR2.appointment_id = AA2.id
LEFT JOIN tb3 as AC2
    on AC2.account_id = AA2.appointment_owner_id
where AR2.status = 'submited'
and AR2.created_at >= '2022-12-30 00:00:00'
and ( to_json(Ac2.expertise::json->0->'id')::text = to_json(Ac.expertise::json->0->'id')::text or ac2.account_id = ac.account_id )
)
```

Comment: Could you please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this statement and the DDL (including indexes) for all tables involved? By the way, some of your LEFT JOINs turn into INNER JOINs because of the WHERE statements.

Comment: See if you can get rid of that `to_json(ac2.expertise) = to_json(ac.expertise)` thing. It's never correct to join tables on expressions, since the database can't use indexes. Make sure you have indexes on tbl1 (status, updated_at) and (status, created_at). If you're only looking at a small time interval, maybe that way it is possible to narrow the number of rows down to avoid parsing the json for every row in tbl1. twice.

Comment: @mikkel: A database can use expressions indexes, just create the index like that. It's not something I would recommend to use for everything, but it is possible and sometimes very powerful.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: Yes, I'm aware. Probably still wouldn't want to join on expression(table1.col) = expression(table2.col)

Comment: Next to writing the `LEFT JOIN`s as `INNER JOIN` as mentioned by @FrankHeikens I'd further adapt the subquery and convert the `NOT IN()` to a `WHERE NOT EXISTS()` syntax. Might not help performance all that much but surely will help readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an index on `tb1` to handle the WHERE clauses you use in your outer query.

```
CREATE INDEX status_updated ON tb1
  (status, updated_at, patient_id);
```

And, create this index to handle your inner query.

```
CREATE INDEX status_created ON tb1
  (status, created_at, patient_id);
```

These work because the query planner can random access these BTREE indexes to the the first eligible row by status and date, and then sequentially scan the index until the last eligible row.

The comments about avoiding `f(column)` expressions in WHERE and ON conditions are correct. You want those conditions to be [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) whenever possible.

And, by the way, you want this for a datestamp range

```
and AR1.updated_at >= '2022-12-30 00:00:00'
and AR1.updated_at < '2022-12-31 00:00:00'
```

You have

```
and AR1.updated_at >= '2022-12-30 00:00:00'
and AR1.updated_at < '2022-12-30 23:59:59'
```

which excludes, rather than includes, rows from the last moment of 2022-12-30. In can be very hard to figure out what went wrong if you exclude a row improperly with a date-range off-by-one-error. (Ask how I know this sometime :-)